# What is behavior of "cout" if passing comma(,) after end of double quotes?

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
private:
    int id = 6;
public:
    friend void display();
};

void display()
{
    base b;
    cout<<"Display id" <<b.id<<endl;
    cout<<"Display id", b.id;
}

int main()
{
    display();  
}
```

**Output:**

```
Display id6
Display id
```

Can someone explain that why `cout<<"Display id", b.id;`  is not throwing error? and if comma (**,**) is acceptable then what will be the behavior of variables written after comma (**,**).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link you have posted above doesn't show what I have asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has a comma operator, `E1, E2` is a perfectly legal expression if `E1` and `E2` are also expressions. It has very low precedence (lower than `<<`) so your example brackets like this

```
(cout<<"Display id"), b.id;
```

The effect of the comma operator is to evaluate what is on the left-hand side first, and then evaluate what is on the right-hand side. The value returned by the whole expression is the value of the right-hand side.

So in terms of your example

```
cout<<"Display id", b.id;
```

is exactly the same as

```
cout<<"Display id";
```

It's very rarely used (and doesn't even exist in other languages like Java) so most newbies have never seen it before. But sometimes you see code like this

```
int ch;
if (ch = in.get(), ch != '\n')
```

which reads a char into `ch` and then checks if it is a newline.